# SARIMA: Fitted values of the time series

Tags: statistics, time-series

I'm trying to forecast future sales via SARIMA model.
Since I have multiple time series, I have used a grid search technique to find the best parameters for the SARIMA model.
But when looking at the fitted values the fit shows a huge dip at September.
Details:
Model fitted on $2$ years of weekly sales.
SARIMA: $(0, 1, 0) \times (1, 1, 0, 52)$ AIC=$4.000$

Can someone explain why is the SARIMA model fit shows such dips. Ideally it show consider it as an outlier.

[image: Graph image]